# How can I combine the values of a single column in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the table in the following format.

```
BatchID BatchTime
1   10:00:00
2   13:00:00
3   16:00:00
4   19:00:00
```

And I what I actually need is:

```
BatchID BatchTime
 1      10:00:00 - 13:00:00
 2      13:00:00 - 16:00:00
 3      16:00:00 - 19:00:00
 4      19:00:00 - 10:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have consecutive `id`s you can do the following:

```
SELECT a.id,a.dt date_a, b.dt date_b FROM tbl a 
INNER JOIN tbl b ON b.id=a.id % (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl) + 1
ORDER BY a.id
```

See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24791/6

Should, however, the times `dt` not be ascending with `id` (which incidentally could also have gaps) then the following will still work:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT id,dt,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt) n FROM tbl)
SELECT a.id,a.dt date_a, b.dt date_b FROM t a 
INNER JOIN t b ON b.n=a.n % (SELECT MAX(n) FROM t) + 1
ORDER BY a.n -- order by ascending times in table a
```

See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74ed6/1

The window function `ROW_NUMBER()` puts the times in an ascending order in the common table expression `t`. After that two `t`s are joined in a cyclic manner (using modulus `%` on the newly generated row number `n`).

`a.n % (SELECT MAX(n) FROM t) + 1` will always calculate the "next" line in the cyclic order with which to join table `t` with alias `b`.